# Android Universal Image Loader to get bitmaps from Another app's Resources

Tags: android, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I know it is possible to use another app's bitmaps using the following blockquote, or similar:

> String packageName = "com.some.package";
>
> Resources res = getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(packageName);
>
> int resId = res.getIdentifier("some_bitmap_icon", "drawable", packageName);
>
> ((BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(resId)).getBitmap();

Is there anyway of passing `res` and `resId`to Android-Universal-Image-Loader to directly load the bitmap from the 3rd party app?

Or would I have to copy the bitmap to the SD card, then display it by passing `"file:///mnt/sdcard/some_temp_bitmap"`

Comment: Since the Universal Image Loader documentation suggests that you not to use it for resources in general ("Use drawable:// only if you really need it! Always consider the native way to load drawables "), why not just use the code that you have in your question?

Comment: Currently, I am using the code I posted to get a large number of bitmaps (from an icon pack), which has started causing an OutOfMemoryError. So I turned to UIL for it's background image loading and caching, hoping it could be used for loading from 3rd party resources.. but I take it this is not the case then?

Comment: I have no idea if UIL has foreign-process drawable support. Looking at [the code](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/download/BaseImageDownloader.java), it does not appear to offer this, at least not as part of `drawable://` syntax. Whether you can create and register a subclass of `BaseImageDownloader`, I can't say.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I've posted my solution below based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare for pointing me in the right direction.

I started by extending `BaseImageDownloader`, and overriding `getStreamFromOtherSource`:

```
public class CustomImageDownloader extends BaseImageDownloader {
    public CustomImageDownloader(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(String imageUri, Object extra) {
        if (imageUri.startsWith("thirdparty://")) {
            try {
                String drawableString = imageUri.replace("thirdparty://", "");
                String[] location = drawableString.split("/");

                Resources res = context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication(location[0]);
                return res.openRawResource(Integer.parseInt(location[1]));
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return null;
            }
        } else throw new UnsupportedOperationException(imageUri);
    }
}
```

Then implemented this class in my ImageLoaderConfiguration using:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .imageDownloader(new CustomImageDownloader(context))
    .build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Then it's just a case of starting the image loader using:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("thirdparty://"+ packageName + "/" + resId, imageView, options);
```

Now [Android universal image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) can be used for loading bitmaps from 3rd party apps.